# Adding youtube player in HTML5 without flash

Tags: ios, html, youtube-javascript-api

Can we add Youtube player in a HTML5 & javascript page without using  flash. I need to make an application which uses youtubeplayer & could be played on differnet platoforms e.g. ios,android

(iOS doesn't support flash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the code for embed videos with fallback to flash for those who doesn't support html5.

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

More info here http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html